# silly question (trig, geom, alg)

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm working through ch 13 of Dummit and Foote (namely 13.3.3). It seems that during the problem, it is supposed to be obvious that b=2k, but I don't see why. [image: trig diagram]

(original construction: Drawing a circle of radius 1 and using the point $A=(k,0)$ as center, construct the point $B=(0,\sqrt{1-k^2})$. Dividing the distance by 3, construct the point $(0,-(1/3)\sqrt{1-k^2})$ and draw the line connecting this point with A. Slide the ruler with marked unit length 1 so that it passes through the point B and so that the distance from the intersection point C to the intersection point D with the x-axis is of length 1.)

Comment: There's definitely some kind of issue here. Name the point $(0,-1/3\sqrt{1-k^2})$ as $E$, and *assume* $D=(3k,0)$. Find the equations of lines $EA$ and $BD$, as well as the coordinates of their intersection $C$. This will show that $|CD|=|AB|$ only if $k=1$, which is a bit problematic for the configuration. ... It's not clear what the remedy should be.